# Back Button issue in Chrome due to cache

Tags: javascript, perl, google-chrome

When ever I press a back button in google chrome browser, For the first click it doesnt navigate instead it store the data in cache and while I press it again it goes back and displays stale information. I am using JS and Perl in my web page. I dont want the data to be cached. I want to stop displaying stale information. Could some body please help me regarding this.
Thanks
Ruban C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell browsers not to cache the pages by sending the appropriate response headers.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

Update: the actual problem is not caused by caching, but by the `history.pushState` usage. It creates a second entry in browser history for the same page, that's why you have to click Back twice. [This MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) explains it in more detail. Consider using `history.replaceState` instead.

Comment: no it didnt work. When I click the back button for first time it doesnt navigate back to the page instead it gets cached I guess. So I have to press again which now displaces stale information. Could you please help me to fix this

Comment: @CArnoldRuban, that's not cache then, that's something else. Maybe you're using History API (manipulating the URL in an address bar)?

Comment: yes I construct URL like using history.pushState. But still why this happens how to get rid of it. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks very much Pressing back button issue has been resolved. But I cant stop page from getting cached :P

Comment: can we set headers using java script if so how ?

Comment: @CArnoldRuban, no, the server must set these headers when responding. I'm not familiar with perl-related software stacks, so can't say how exactly.